# C# HttpClient's PostAsync fails when HttpRuntime's TargetFramework is set to 4.8

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, httpruntime

I am facing an issue with the C# HttpClient's PostAsync method. I am calling an API which is on HTTPS SSL and things are working fine until I deployed my code on to a server which has the following in the web.config

```
var response = await Client.PostAsync(path, requestObject);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string strResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

The API being called is on HTTPS and the certificate is trusted on my machine.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="40960" **targetFramework="4.8" **enableVersionHeader="false" />
```

My local environment doesn't have the targetFramework in the web.config. The API call only works if I remove the TargetFramework attribute. After adding the attribute back, there seems to be no errors or response, the execution hangs for 5 minutes. There is no exception or error, nothing in the event viewer.

I have tried a lot of things like setting the TLS

```
Security.Transport.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12;
```

and

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= 
    SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

But nothing seems to work. We need the targetframework attribute and need this api call to work. What is the TargetFramework attribute adding in terms of configuration which is leading to api call failing/hanging ?

Comment: Why don't you enable that also on your dev machine and take a closer look with the debugger what is happening? It sounds weird to me telling the system via the config to use some sort of compatibility mode when you haven't developed in that mode.

Comment: Have you checked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/retargeting/4.0-4.8#networking

Comment: @Ralf I have debugged and the execution stops at when invoking the post api call. I am not able to debug the real issue.  No exception is thrown, no error is shown and breakpoint in  next line never gets hit.

Comment: @NitinA: Are you [blocking on asynchronous code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)?

Comment: @StephenCleary No, I don't think so, since it's works 10/10 times when I remove the target framework attribute.

Comment: @NitinA: The target framework attribute turns on and off server-side quirks mode, which changes the `SynchronizationContext` used for ASP.NET requests, which is part of what causes sync-over-async deadlocks. So it *could* be related to the issue you're seeing.

Comment: @StephenCleary, Thank you for the wonderful suggestion. I have realized that the issue is due to a deadlock. I have made the changes and it works now. Please elaborate your suggestion as an answer, would be happy to mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`targetFramework` controls the server-side "quirks mode". One of those "quirks" is which `SynchronizationContext` to use. Without the `targetFramework` setting, ASP.NET uses the `LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext`, which doesn't work correctly with `async` and `await`. With the `targetFramework` setting, ASP.NET uses `AspNetSynchronizationContext`, which does work with `async` and `await`.

If your code is [blocking on asynchronous code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), then it's possible that the old/legacy `SynchronizationContext` will not cause a deadlock when it actually *should*. Note that removing the `targetFramework` is not the correct solution, since the old/legacy `SynchronizationContext` shouldn't be used with `async`/`await` at all. The proper solution is to remove the blocking so that no deadlock can occur with the new `SynchronizationContext`.